# Magento2 How to add field data in additional_data in custom payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

test-payment.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'payfort_start',
                component: 'Spacename_Test/js/view/payment/method-renderer/test-payment'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */

        return Component.extend({
            getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'additional_data': {
                    'test1': this.test1(),
                    'test': this.test()
                }
            };
        }
        });
    }
);
```

method-renderer/test-payment.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (Component, $) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Spacename_Test/payment/test-form'
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'testing';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },

            validate: function() {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            },
            getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'additional_data': {
                    'test1': this.test1(),
                    'test': this.test()
                }
            };
        }
        });
    }
);
```

html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
        <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ccard ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
            <input type="text" name="payment[test]">
            <input type="text" name="payment[test1]">
            <div id="payfortCardDetails">
            </div> 


            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>             



        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button  class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place Order')"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i figured it out how to pass the data to additional

i change the form and add ids for elemenets

```
  <div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
        <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ccard ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
            <input type="text" name="payment[test]" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()+'_test'}">
            <input type="text" name="payment[test1]" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()+'_test1'}">
            <div id="payfortCardDetails">
            </div> 


            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>             



        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button  class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place Order')"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

changing the **getData** i am getting the values now

```
getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'additional_data': {
                    'test1':  $('#' +this.getCode() +'_test1').val(),
                    'test': $('#' +this.getCode() +'_test').val()
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: @PriyaM sorry i don't get what kind of message you want to display?

Comment: Thanks for replay...i want to show text-message under cod payment method

Comment: @PriyaM you can use instruction that are available in cod payment method configuration.

Comment: i'm not familiar in that.

Comment: @PriyaM go to admin panel -> store -> configuration -> payment method -> cash on delivery  and add your message in instruction.

Comment: @PriyaM you can manipulate the cod js. it is an idea never implement it.

Comment: still not getting msg.....how to solve this